# Sharing git repo on DreamHost

Tags: git, users, dreamhost

I have a git repo on DreamHost that I would like to be able to share with other developers.  I am only able to create it in my home directory.  How do I get it so that other devs can access it via ssh?  Here's what I've tried:

I created a group, put all devs into that group and chowned the repo to be owned by the group.  If I clone the repo as me like this:

```
git clone ssh://ME@host/~/projects/repo.git
```

Then it works.  I tried having them use their ssh credentials to clone the resource like this:

```
git clone ssh://THEM@host/home/ME/projects/repo.git
```

and that failed.  So then I tried making a softlink in their home to the repo in mine and having them do:

```
git clone ssh://THEM@host/~/projects/repo.git
```

And that failed.

-= Update =-
My directory structure looks like this:

```
~/projects/repo.git
```

Where both `project` and `repo.git` are owned by my git group and have `drwxrwx---` permissions.  When I try:

```
ssh://THEM@host/~ME/projects/repo.git
```

I get

```
fatal: '~ME/projects/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`
```

Comment: Can the other users log in to the server interactively? If so, what do they see if they run `git --git-dir ~ME/projects/repo.git describe --all` and `ls -a ~ME/projects/repo.git/`?

Comment: There we go!  I thought that I had set my root to a+x but I guess I hadn't!  It's working now!  Thank you so much!

Comment: There is an old saying amongst the unix folk to the extent that it always always turns out to be a problem of paths and permissions. This is no exception!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other developers will also need execute permission on your home directory and the projects directory. Perhaps read permission, too, although i doubt it. Do they have that?

For what it's worth, they should be able to use this URL, which is perhaps the cleanest:

```
ssh://THEM@host/~ME/projects/repo.git
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the results of this.